# How can I convert django model object and related object in to list of dictionary?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models

The model will be like

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Payment(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2) 
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, models.CASCADE)
```

and I want make a list like

```
[
    {
        'name': 'Tom',
        'Payment': [{'amount': 10},{'amount': 20}]
    ｝，
    {
        'name': 'Jack',
        'Payment': [{'amount': 30},{'amount': 10}]
    ｝
]
```

I tried to use values but it require me to know all the field name for related object Is there other way to do this without knowing field name?

Comment: Well, in your example (at least certain) names play special role. E.g. the attribute `customer` is not printed, `payment` is lower case of a class name... So that it's not straightforward how you want to generalize this case.

Comment: My bad Payment's P should be upper case. I want the converter to ignore foreign key field cause the information about the foreign key is already stored in the list(Customer)

Comment: Where you want to use this list? If in some API, you should use some REST framework (Django Rest Framework i.e.) and use `serializers` to convert your set of models (QuerySet) to serialized structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
q_customer = Customer.objects.all()
L = []
for customer in q_custmer:
  Dcustomer = {'name':customer.name,
         'Payment':[{'amount',x.amount} for x in customer.payment_set]
  L.append[D]

# L now holds the list
```